# How to delete substring beginning with "#blah" until end?

Tags: javascript

Assume I want to delete a substring which starts with `"#blah"` until the end of string. `#blah` itself should be deleted too.

How can I achieve this? e.g.
`var address = document.URL.replace("#blah","");`
deletes only the keyword but not the following, remaining part.

If `"#blah"` is not found in string then nothing should happen.

Comment: I would start by finding the index of "#blah" with `String.indexOf()`.  Then use `String.substring()` to find the exact match of all the text, then replace that text with `String.replace()`.

Comment: `.replace(/#blah.*/,"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a regex matching `blah#` and everything that comes after it.

```js
const myText = "address.com/stuff/things#blah-and-other-stuff";
const blahRegex = /#blah.*$/;
const withoutBlah = myText.replace(blahRegex, "");
console.log(`Before: ${myText}`);
console.log(`After ${withoutBlah}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Regex

[`/#blah.*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/giWk9y/1) will replace the matched pattern and everything afterwards.

```js
const url1 = "https://example.com/#blah";
const url2 = "https://example.com/#blah/something-else";
const url3 = "https://example.com/";

const result1 = url1.replace(/#blah.*$/, "");
const result2 = url2.replace(/#blah.*$/, "");
const result3 = url3.replace(/#blah.*$/, "");

console.log(result1); // Output: "https://example.com/"
console.log(result2); // Output: "https://example.com/"
console.log(result3); // Output: "https://example.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that regex is the way to go here.

If you wish you can also achieve the result using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) & [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```js
const removeBlah = (word) => {
    var index = example.indexOf("#blah")
    if(index >=0){
        return example.substring(0,index);
    }   else {
        return word
    }
}

var example = "www.example.com/#blah"
console.log(removeBlah(example))

example = "www.example.com/#blah/page"
console.log(removeBlah(example))

example = "www.example.com/"
console.log(removeBlah(example))
```